# Can anything else occur in this case other than simple square root of matrices?

Tags: matrices

Let $M$ and $N$ be two square matrices of same order, and $M^2 = N^4$.

Can any such $M,N$ exist when the following relations do not hold?

1. $M = N^2$, and
2. $M = -N^2$ ?

Comment: I am not sure what should be the title of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of nilpotent matrices.  So, pick $M$ of degree 2 and $N$ of degree 4.

Or look for roots of the identity matrix.  $M$ could be any reflection and $N$ a rotation by 90 degrees.

Comment: I could not understand the reflection and rotation part. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Any reflection, $M$, will be self inverse hence $M^2 = I$.  A rotation, $N$, by 90 degrees will satisfy $N^4 = I$.  Hence d $M^2 = N^4$ as you wanted.

Comment: The odd letter "d" just "Hence" is a strange typo.

Comment: Reflexion and rotation matrices are new terms to me. Could you please provide some detailed explanations or links to explanations? I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix in wikipedia and have noticed that fourth power of $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      \cos\frac \pi2&-\sin\frac \pi2\\
      \cos\frac \pi2&\sin\frac \pi2
    \end{array}
\right] $$ is identity matrix. Did you mean this?

Comment: Matrices are commonly used to represent linear transformations.  A $2\times2$ matrix can be used to represent a linear transformation of the plane.  

This matrix 

$$\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&-1\cr}$$

reflects the plane through the x-axis.  Its square is the identity matrix.  

Your example rotates the plane by 90 degrees.  Its square is a 180 degree rotation and its fourth power is the identity.  

If you have not seen matrices used for this purpose, what have you seen them used for?

Comment: I am a high school student. So far I have only learnt to solve 
 a system of equations with matrices.

Comment: That explains it.  If that is your only experience of matrices so far then I can see that this question would be tough.  I hope that you will learn about matrices representing linear transformations soon and then it should make much more sense.  Later, you may learn about abstract algebra.  Note that matrix multiplication is not commutative so $A \times B = B \times A$ is not always true.  Also, not all matrices have an inverse so from $A \times B = A \times C$ you cannot deduce that $B = C$ even if you know that $A \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$M=N=\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0\cr}$$